# How to get full URL of the image used as background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, background-image

I want to get a link to download image that is used as a background.

The URL information is stored in `background('images/image.jpg')`

Two problems here:

- URL is wrapped by `background('')`
- URL is relative and for download I need absolute URL

I used RegEx to get rid of the `background('')`, and appended the site URL.

Is there a more simple and efficient solution I am not aware? Perhaps using jQuery?

Comment: prepend `window.location.host` after having removed background('');

Comment: thanks, it's something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.getComputedStyle(SELECTOR, null).getPropertyValue('background-image').split("\'")[1]
```

Comment: Try explaining your approach before just pasting a simple line of code.

Comment: @Boykodev `window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0], null).getPropertyValue('background-image').split(/'|"/)[1]` works like a charm.